# Orthogonal Transformation about [110] axis

Tags: matrices, transformation, orthogonality

I am pretty stuck on this problem listed below and don't understand what [110] means here. If anyone could help I would really appreciate it.

Suppose p is a vector in R^3 and you want to rotate p about the axis [110] by an angle theta. Find the matrix R such that q = Rp.

Again mostly trying to understand what the question is really asking here instead of a direct solution.

Comment: I would presume that it means around the line joining the origin an the point $(1,1,0)^T$. So, to rotate a point $x$, think of the plan perpendicular to the line that passes through $x$, and rotate $x$ by $\theta$ in that plane.

Comment: Still don't really understand, there is a hint that says to rotate the coordinates so that one of your principal axes is [110], then rotate by theta, then rotate the coordinates back. Super confused by this

Comment: You need to draw a picture.

Comment: One way is to figure out how each of the unit vectors $(1,0,0)^T, (0,1,0)^T, (0,0,1)^T$ are rotated.